# WiX Installer: How to switch to repair-mode if already installed?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am new to WiX 3.0 and writing my first installer based on WiX (coming from Wise).

If the product is already installed (in the current version), I want the installer to switch to "repair"-mode automatically. It should behave exactly like as if I would have clicked "repair" in the Windows software dialog.

It must behave like this to fit in the overall installation process of the system.

I read the documentation but can't get hold of the problem...

Comment: As far as I understand you need to change the sequence of the UI dialogs. I don't know how can this be done conditionally, so let's wait for answers.

Comment: Note: the installer is without UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Installed property to conditionalize a SetProperty element for REINSTALL and REINSTALLMODE properties. Be careful to test upgrades to ensure that you add the other parts of the condition (REMOVE<>"ALL") so that the upgrade of the old product stays an uninstall and doesn't flip to repair. :)

Comment: Thanks Rob. This solution seems to work:

<SetProperty Id="REINSTALL" Value="ALL" After="FindRelatedProducts" >Installed AND REMOVE&lt;&gt;"ALL"</SetProperty>
  
<SetProperty Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="vamus" After="FindRelatedProducts">Installed AND REMOVE&lt;&gt;"ALL"</SetProperty>

Comment: Be sure to test upgrade and patching before releasing to make sure everything is good. You won't be able to fix it later. :)